# is it possible to use single view for multiple methods and controllers with different data?

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, laravel-blade

I need to use single `view` multiple time with different `methods` as well `controllers` all `methods` are sending different data and on submit it effect to different `table` of `database`.

suppose i have two `methods`, `method1` and `method2`

`method1` has data like `{123,456,789}` and go to view with this data and on submit, need to make changes in `table1` of my database.

`method2` has data like`{321,654,987}` and go to view with this data and on submit, need to make changes in `table2` of my database.

i don't have any idea about to reuse the `view` with different `data`, if it is possible then please help me.

Comment: surely you can reuse the view in Laravel, you can simply pass the form action attribute as a blade parameter and based on the Form action you can update the data in different tables.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Surely you can use same view for different Laravel methods which will not make any difference what so ever.

Eg.
In `UserController@login` method you can `return view('login');`
and the same view can be returned in `CustomerController@login` method also.

you just need to change the Form Action in `login.blade.php` based on the Controller who is returning the view.

Comment: Thanks you give me hint, i can also pass `route name` , `action{{controller@mehod}}` form method with view.

Comment: yes, you can do that or you won't even need to pass action route since, the forms are by default submitted to the same route you can handle the post request in the same controller method which is returning the view using `$request->isMethod('get')` then `return view` `else if($request->isMethod('post'))` then handle posted data. @HirenMangukiya

Comment: can you explain your last comment in brief?

Comment: By default HTML forms are submitted on the same URL if you don't mention the Action in HTML form, so what I suggest is you can have a form in your blade file with `method="post"` without action attribute and it will be submitted to the same URL and if form is in the route `example.com/customer/login` then the form without action attribute will be submitted by default on `example.com/customer/login`, I hope that helped @HirenMangukiya

Answer (score -1):

```
public function func1(data){
  return view("document",[data]);
}
public function func2(data){
  return view("document",[data]);
}
```